# Is it okay to create a expiring timestamp cache table?

Tags: php, sql, caching, yii

I was reading about caching mechanism that Yii implements and possible other frameworks/techniques/databases as well. If I got that right, there's a step that you have to specify a condition to expire the cache. If you have a user row with a timestamp field, you could use this timestamp to verify it's (the row) consistency. If you have a log table with non erasable/updatable rows, you could use **count(*)** to make sure that you have an up to date cached result of that query/table.

Now, to my question:

Imagine that I have 13 tables. Is it **useful** to create another table (**CacheTable**) that has only one column of **timestamp** type and store **13 rows**, each row telling me when was the last time that one of the other tables was updated/deleted/inserted and use this **CacheTable** to verify the expiring condition of all my cached queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a good solution if you plan to create triggers to update the **CacheTable**, you don't want to do the updates in your code as it will become hard to maintain later.

Comment: But is this really useful? It outperforms the cache that the database does by itself? Or maybe another way to do it without relying on a table?

Comment: whatever you do, if you are thinking on CDbCacheDependency (http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCacheDependency) you'll end up hitting the database, maybe take a look at some other cache dependency options? http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/caching.data#cache-dependency

Comment: Yes, I was thinking about CDbCacheDependency. I got no problem going to the database to perform a query. I just wanted to know if using this worths the trouble in some situations. I'm guessing it worths.